# I dont want my image to come back after applying styles

Tags: css

i have a problem with a image that i placed on my site here is what i done.

```
    #mysecond
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:none;
    position:relative;
    animation:mysecond 5s;
    -webkit-animation:mysecond 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */ 
    -moz-animation    : mysecond 5s;
    -o-animation      : mysecond 5s;
    animation         : mysecond 5s;
    }
    @keyframes mysecond 
    {
    from {
    transform : scale(1.5);
    opacity   : 1;
    }
    to {
    transform : scale(0);
    opacity   : .0;
    }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes {
    from {
    transform : scale(1.5);
    opacity   : 1;
    }
    to {
    transform : scale(0);
    opacity   : .0;
    }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes {
    from {
    transform : scale(1.5);
    opacity   : 1;
    }
    to {
    transform : scale(0);
    opacity   : .0;
    }
    }
```

after all this my game plan was to make the image scale and disappear, instead it did scale and disappear but after the hole 5 seconds it came back any ideas what i have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Set the end state at the beginning.**

```
#mysecond{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:none;
 position:relative;
 -webkit-animation:mysecond 5s;
 /*missing*/
 -webkit-transform:scale(0);
 opacity:0;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/agj7z/2/

**BTW you need to change class if you want to hide it after an event:**

*Hide after 2 seconds*

js

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('mysecond').classList.add('hide');
},2000);
```

css

```
#mysecond{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:red;
 -webkit-transform:scale(1);
 opacity:1;
}

#mysecond.hide{
 -webkit-animation:mysecond 5s;
 -webkit-transform:scale(0);
 opacity:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mysecond{
 0%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  opacity:1;
 }
 100%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(0);
  opacity:0;
 }
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/agj7z/3/

if you have any questions just ask.